# Proliant DL380 G5, MSA60, Opensuse 13.1

Tags: linux, hp, opensuse, partition

I should apologize for my limited English.
I bought recently an used MSA60, to replace a set of small e-SATA boxes. The disks they contain are mostly 3T bytes SATA ones. When I put the disks in the MSA60, the only one that can be mounted is a 2TB one.
The others are detected, but their ext4 partitions do not appear. They exist only as /dev/sd... devices. They have GPT partition tables.
The MSA60 is linked to a LSI SAS 1068E controller in the server (DL380).
I read some posts, including in this forum, that prove that it is way to use disks larger than 2T in the MSA60.
I will be very grateful for any hint.
Yours
H. Delebecque

Comment: Did you verify that the MSA60 is running firmware v1.50 or newer? What SAS card are you using (1068E is a chip, not a card)? I have a MSA60 with 3TB drives connected to a LSI 9201-8i (2008 chip) at home, works great.

Comment: Thanks a lot also for proving that my MSA60 can do the right job. The card is actually a LSI Logic SAS3442. I found a message from the MSA60 in the server log telling: "Enclosure HP MSA60 2.18". Does it imply that the firmware is 2.18 ? And if so, please, ould you give me some hints for flashing it with a newer version ?

Comment: Yep, 2.18 is the version and it's new enough. If you want to flash a newer version you'd need an HP P-Series SAS card, HP locks the update process to their own hardware. How about the firmware on the SAS card? It should be Firmware version 01.33.00.00 and BIOS version 6.36.00.00

Comment: Hello, the firmware version seems to be 01172b00h (according to the message "LSISAS1068E B3, FwRev=01172b00h"). I browsed forums, and I think that the problem came from it: this model seems to not allow drives larger than 2 TB. I ordered an used "LSI SATA/SAS 9201-8i card" on ebay. I hope that it will work like yours. Thanks a lot. Best regards

Comment: FYI, the 9201-8i does not have an external SFF-8088 port (the "8i" means "8 internal" ports), mine's connected through a HP SAS Expander (allows me to connect the LSI card to 16 SAS drives in the server and has the external SFF-8088 for the MSA60, and aggregate all 8 lanes). The 8i could be used with a SFF-8087 to 88 cable strung through an open PCI slot, or with a 87/88 PCI Bracket as well. Or the 9200-8e is the same chip with two SFF-8088 ports.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Please, could you tell me if I should take care of the firmware version for this kind of HBA ? Best regards

Comment: I'd always recommend updating to the latest firmware when installing new hardware or troubleshooting a problem. Since LSI HBAs generally require DOS to update the firmware I keep a bootable USB stick around with all the relevant utilities. The latest firmware is available for all the cards we've mentioned on LSI's website. I'm running the old MSA60 v1.5 firmware without issues, and it's a hassle to update, so I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: I'm not very comfortable with DOS, even if I can use basic commands with it. I prefer clearly Linux, and my usual platform is a Mac. I found an old version of the HP firmware CD, and will try to write it on a USB key, adding the specific LSI stuff. Thanks for your help